# do javascript constructor function creates an object called this and return it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor

As of my knowledge, constructor function are just like normal functions (For convention we just uppercasing it).
When we prefix it with `new` it becomes a constructor function which creates an object and returns it

```
function Foo(prop){
let this = {};
this.prop=prop;
return this;
}
```

Is this actually happens internally when we try to add a `new` keyword before any function.

Comment: `let this = {};` is a syntax error.